# Generate bitmap texture from bitmap font and string

Tags: linux, fonts, bitmaps

I downloaded [nice bitmap fonts](http://upperbounds.net/index.php?menu=download) and I can easily convert them to many other bitmap font formats (.fon,.sfd ...) using [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/)

but I'm missing very basic thing - how to generate actual bitmap image?

Given input text string like this (enumeration ASCII characters 32...126 ):

`!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~`

I want to get output picture like this:

[image]

Why? Because my 3D engine cannot read .fon or .sfd format, it can read images and use them as texture atlas

Comment: Have a look at [ttf2png](http://www.tdb.fi/ttf2png.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

You could try pbmtext from the netpbm toolkit. It can read a couple different font formats (BDF, PBM) and generate images using the font.